# If $|a_{n+1}-a_n| = \mathcal{O}(1/n)$ and $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \to 0$ then $a_n \to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was recently reading a paper, where the following step was made: suppose that $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence such that
$$
|a_{n+1}-a_n| = \mathcal{O}(1/n)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \to 0, \quad N \to \infty.
$$
According to the author it follows that $a_n \to 0$. Is this always true? It seems like some Tauberian theorem to me.

Comment: Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2429523/399263, I've not read all but seems the answer is in the post related to baby Rudin.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1106820/42969